# C++ dll with .NET: are memory leaks determinate?

Tags: c++, dll, memory-leaks

I have Windows Forms(C#) application, which uses C++ dll(unmanaged code). Image is loaded, then dll function is called to process it. 
The problem is: **exception: std::bad_alloc** is thrown when I call function from dll several times in a row. *Maybe* problem is because of not deleting memory in dll, and *maybe* because of garbage collecor in Windows Forms.
How to determine which project in application causes memory leak?

Comment: Use a memory profiler or heap debugger.  I'd definitely start with an unmanaged one first.  Umdh.exe has the right price.

Answer (score 1):

I meet the similar problem recently, I design a useful solution to the problem. You can write a deconstruct function named such as "freeObject" , just different from the ~*** function, and you should explicitly call the "freeObject" function . Here is an example .

```
void VideoAbstraction::freeObject(){
    videoCapture.~VideoCapture();
    videoWriter.~VideoWriter();
    backgroundImage.release();              
    currentStartIndex.release();
    currentEndIndex.release();
    mog.~BackgroundSubtractorMOG2();
    gFrame.release();           
    gForegroundMask.release();  
    gBackgroundImg.release();   
    currentMask.release();  
    vector<ObjectCube>().swap(partToCompound);  
    vector<Mat>().swap(compoundResult);
    vector<Mat>().swap(indexs);
    vector<Mat>().swap(indexe);
    vector<int>().swap(frame_start);
    vector<int>().swap(frame_end); 
}
```

and the out calling part is like that.

```
void UserVideoAbstraction::UserfreeObject(){
    userVB->freeObject();
}
```